# SoftMax derivative calculation: Error: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate the derivative of the SoftMax function but I'm unable to call it relieving an error mentioned below.

```
def softmax_grad(self,s):
    print('s.shape:',s.shape)
    jacobian_m = np.diag(s)
    print('jacobian_m:',jacobian_m.ndim)
    for i in range(len(jacobian_m)):
        print('i:',i)
        for j in range(len(jacobian_m)):
            print('j:',j)
            if i == j:
                jacobian_m[i][j] = s[i] * (1-s[i])
            else:
                jacobian_m[i][j] = -s[i]*s[j]
    return jacobian_m

def train(self, inputs, targets, eta, niterations):
    ndata = np.shape(inputs)[0] # number of data samples 
    # adding the bias
    inputs = np.concatenate((inputs,-np.ones((ndata,1))),axis=1)
    
    # numpy array to store the update weights 
    updatew1 = np.zeros((np.shape(self.weights1))) 
    updatew2 = np.zeros((np.shape(self.weights2)))
    updatew3 = np.zeros((np.shape(self.weights3)))
    
   
    for n in range(niterations):   
        # forward phase 
        self.outputs = self.forwardPass(inputs)
  
    
        # Error using the sum-of-squares error function
        error = 0.5*np.sum((self.outputs-targets)**2)
   
        if (np.mod(n,100)==0):
            print("Iteration: ",n, " Error: ",error)
    
            deltao = self.sigmoid_derivative(self.outputs)
            print('delto :',deltao)
```

After running the following code I'm facing with an error 
`TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: Where does the error occur?   We don't like to guess!

Comment: At the following line of softmax_grad function: 
jacobian_m[i][j] = s[i] * (1-s[i])

Comment: What is the shape of S?

Comment: `jacobian_m` doesn't have enough dimensions to index with 2 layers

Comment: @M.Soyturk s.shape: (9000, 10)

Comment: @hpaulj `jacobian_m.ndim` is showing 1. Can you please tell how can I eliminate the error should i reshape it?

Answer (score 0):

np.diag returns a 1D array consisting of the diagonal elements of the given parameter if the parameter is a 2D array (which is 's' in your case). That's why you receive 1 when you try to get ndim. So, your jacobian_m variable is a 1D array and you are trying to use it like it is a 2D array which causes the error.

Comment: i reshape `jacobian_m `and now it's (2,4500). But it was throwing an error **“assignment destination is read-only”** so I tried this `jacobian_m .setflags(write=1)` now it's showing **ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.**

Comment: As the error indicates, you are trying to write a sequence (a list) to an array element. It is not allowed.